# Why fetch blocked if it get redirect to mixed content

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Request from HTML page works in following steps:

1) After https:// link was clicked, we get 302 code and get header location to HTTP:// . Browser follows this
2) Server got request from HTTP and set header location to HTTPS://
3) Browser get content from HTTPS://

Yes, this is stupid but I don't have access to the server.

When I try to send request from Firefox console with fetch with settings

```
mode: 'cors',
credentials: 'include',
redirect: 'follow'
```

..but error:

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

When I set :

```
mode: 'no-cors',
```

All redirects work fine but body response is absent.

Seems like mixed content blocked by fetch?

I use two fetch requests (second with https hardcoded) for redirects excluding. Is there a solution in one fetch request?

Comment: If you hardcode the `fetch` to use `https://` in the first place (as a diagnostic), do you get the content? Maybe the server isn't configured to allow CORS from your origin (at least over HTTPS).

Comment: Fix the server so it doesn't bounce the client through an insecure end point (which would be subject to interception).

Comment: All requests from client side with https. Server respond Location: http:// and browser follow to this and server set new location again but with https. i hardcoded https in second fetch request and it worked.

Comment: @Quentin i dont have access to the server